# Syntax Error pivoting a SQL table using string columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table **Occupation** like such:

```
Name | Occupation
-----------------
Sam  | Doctor
Joe  | Professor
John | Actor
Hailey | Singer
April | Doctor
```

My goal is to utilize the PIVOT function to display each distinct Occupation as their own column like so:

```
Doctor | Professor | Singer | Actor
-----------------------------------
Sam    | Joe       | Hailey  | John
April
```

I went through various stack overflow questions with similar issues, and even utilized the documentation here and followed step by step. My efforts have been futile, so what gives? I am receiving a syntax error every time I run this code. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
SELECT *
FROM(SELECT Name, Occupation from Occupations) as src
PIVOT
(MAX(Name) FOR Name IN [Doctor], [Professor], [Singer], [Actor]) as piv;
```

I am solving this problem on Hackerrank, and the compiler was MySQL. I changed it to MSSQL and am no longer receiving a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing 2 ()  One on each side in the PIVOT part, I bolded the brackets I added:

**(**[Doctor], [Professor], [Singer], [Actor]**)**  - These 2

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Name, Occupation 
    FROM Occupations
) as src
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Name) FOR Name IN ([Doctor], [Professor], [Singer], [Actor])
) as piv;
```

Comment: I noticed that silly mistake, my fault. Although, I still receive a syntax error upon fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

This query will generate the answer as per the way you need. The above answer does not provide the answer as the way you required. Try this answer.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

--Making the column list dynamically 
SELECT @cols  = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+QUOTENAME(  [T2].[Occupation]) 
               FROM  Occupation_data [T2]              
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')              


 --preparing PIVOT query dynamically. 

 SET @SQL = ' SELECT 

            *
          into #temp
          FROM 
          (
          SELECT row_number() over (order by name) as id,  [Name], [Occupation]
          FROM Occupation_data
          ) AS cp
          PIVOT
          (
           min([Name]) FOR [Occupation] IN (' + @cols + ')
          ) AS up;  
             
                
          Select               
          row_number() over (order by doctor asc ) as id1
          ,*
          into  #temp_1
          from #temp where Doctor is not null
         
                     
          Select 
          row_number() over (Order by Actor asc ) as id2
          ,*
          into #temp_2
          from #temp where Actor is not null
                  
         
          Select 
          row_number() over (Order by Professor asc ) as id3
          ,*
          into #temp_3
          from #temp where Professor is not null
        
          Select 
          row_number() over (Order by Singer asc ) as id4
          ,*
          into #temp_4
          from #temp where Singer is not null


          select 
          A.Doctor
          ,B.Actor
          ,C.Professor
          ,D.Singer
          from 
          #temp_1 A inner join 
          #temp_2 B ON A.id1 = B.id2 
          INNER JOIN
          #temp_3  C ON A.id1 = C.id3
          INNER JOIN  
          #temp_4 D ON A.id1 = d.id4
        

          drop table #temp 
          drop table #temp_1
          drop table #temp_2
          drop table #temp_3
          drop table #temp_4

  ';

  PRINT( @SQL)
  EXEC (@SQL)
```

Output: [image: Result]

If this answer works for you I will make it more generic and give you so that you can apply this for any work like this.

Comment: @nick_rinaldi Check this answer and let me know.